# BigQuery: How to see a part of the string?

Tags: string, split, google-bigquery

I have a database that looks like

```
 Alex,Anna,Peter
 Alex
 Alex,Peter
 Alfons
 Algebra,Geometry
 Algebra,Physics
```

However I am only interested in the first expression before the comma. Meaning my perfect answer would be:

```
Alex
Alex
Alex
Alfons
Algebra
Algebra
```

So far I found the SPLIT function but it still returns me a bunch of values I am really not interested in. How to make it run efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT first(split(s,','))
FROM
  (SELECT 'Alex,Anna,Peter' AS s),
  (SELECT 'Algebra,Geometry' AS s);
```

Outputs:

```
Alex     
Algebra
```

Answer (score 0):

SPLIT could be expensive, since it translates string into repeated field, so here are two more alternative solutions:

```
SELECT IFNULL(LEFT(s, INSTR(s, ',') - 1), s)
FROM
  (SELECT 'Alex,Anna,Peter' AS s),
  (SELECT 'Algebra,Geometry' AS s),
  (SELECT 'Alfons' AS s)
```

and

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(s, r'([^,]*)')
FROM
  (SELECT 'Alex,Anna,Peter' AS s),
  (SELECT 'Algebra,Geometry' AS s),
  (SELECT 'Alfons' AS s)
```